# How could I use the uploaded image with no suffix of the server to the html page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```
$('#userInfoPhoto').html(function () {
    return '<img src="../uploads/' + thisUserObject.profileimage + '" alt = "userphoto" style="width:250px; height:250px"/>'
});
```

This is the front end js
how could I use the upload file in the image folder like this and the thisUserObject.profileimage is the name of the file (just a file with no suffix)
[image]

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of the `../uploads` part or the extension of the image?

Answer (score 0):

if you are just trying to remove the file extension, you could do it with a regular expression.

```
thisUserObject.profileimage.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, I just make some mistake about the upload directory, the image folder should be put in the public folder, the html page could recognize the file without no suffix and add it into the html page.

[image]